# Efficient method names for formulas?

Tags: oop, coding-style

I have a problem regarding method names. My project has the following folders Physics -> Equations -> Mechanics. This is where I intend to create classes with methods that allows me to calculate various equations. The problem lies with how to give those methods meaningful names that would explain their useage. To my knowledge each and every equation doesn't come with a name that helps us differentiate between them.
I tried to give my methods names according to their endresult and it seemed working just fine however there is a limit to overloading methods. My input variables are so far only doubles.

What is the best practice to this?

Comment: use the best you can names. i can't tell how to call them... use intelisense or regular comment to explain what the equation does

Comment: Can you describe what some of the methods do, to give us a sense of what you're dealing with? If you can describe their intent, I would guess that you can name them. You may have to put up with some pretty long names, that's all. And can you give us some of your "endresult" names? What do you mean by "efficient", by the way?

Answer (score 0):

[From Oracle Docs:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

> Naming a Method
>
> Although a method name can be any legal identifier, code conventions
>   restrict method names. By convention, method names should be a verb in
>   lowercase or a multi-word name that begins with a verb in lowercase,
>   followed by adjectives, nouns, etc. In multi-word names, the first
>   letter of each of the second and following words should be
>   capitalized. Here are some examples:
>
> run runFast getBackground getFinalData compareTo setX isEmpty
>   Typically, a method has a unique name within its class. However, a
>   method might have the same name as other methods due to method
>   overloading.

Comment: Note, the casing conventions depend on completely on the language. In C#/VB.NET, for example, method names typically begin with a capital letter, whereas Java usually begins with lowercase. I guess the most important thing to pull from that Oracle doc is that "method names should be a verb [...] followed by adjectives, nouns, etc." Methods = verbs, classes = nouns.

Comment: @valverij Yes, true. Since the OP did not specify the language I mentioned the source too. Oracle Docs. Hopefully that should help.

Comment: Hurrah for verb naming -- IF it does a verb thing. If it's a predicate, call it IsVisible() or whatever. But all this dude's methods probably begin with the verb Calculate, which doesn't help much. In fact, I'd probably put them in a static class called Calculate, call that the verb prefix, and name them with nouns for the concept being calculated. EnergyFromMassVelocity(double mass, double velocity), or whatever. Lower-case it if that's the language convention, of course.

Comment: Well yeah, "Is" is a verb. Derp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameter types in method name: ie.

```
DistanceBySpeedAndTime(double speed, double time);
DistanceByAccelerationAndTime(double acceleration, double time);
```